# Having trouble connecting to neo4j with neo4jClient Everyman

Tags: php, neo4j, connection, graph-databases

I am creating a project using php in eclipse and neo4j. I am having problems connecting though. This is the code I have written to connect to the database.

```
<?php
include("neo4jphp.phar");
use Everyman\Neo4j\Client;

$neo4jClient = new \Everyman\Neo4j\Client('https://127.0.0.1:7474',7474);

$neo4jClient->getTransport()
->setAuth('username','password')
->getTransport()->useHttps();
```

and here is the link to show the error I am having.
Link: https://selene.hud.ac.uk/irr/connect.php

According to my research this should be correct. I am also using this video to help me with the connection: https://vimeo.com/125334699

Some guidance in the right direction using my code will be appreciated.

Comment: The link https://selene.hud.ac.uk/irr/connect.php is broken.

Comment: Yes that is the problem it doesn't work

Comment: The error I am getting is HTTP ERROR 500